# Change between fragment navigation drawer viewpagerindicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, viewpagerindicator

I have a Navigation Drawer and a ViewPagerIndicator inside the content_frame. I want to change between fragment`s from the navigation drawer but the problem is that switch between tabs **ViewPager** works but when I switch to another option that you have to remove the **ViewPager** and put a new fragment puts this fragment under the **ViewPager**.

Attached photo so you can see.

1) Here you can already see the new fragment below ViewPager.It can be distinguished by the text shown is **Prueba**

[image]

Attached code

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout         
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
 android:dividerHeight="0dp"
 android:background="#111"/>
```

Method for switching between fragment.

```
   /** Main content by replacing fragments
 * @param position
 */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    //Code
    Fragment fragment = new TryFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        break;

    case 1:
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        break;

    case 2:

        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

        break;

    }        
    ft.commit();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Class TryFragment

```
    class TryFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static final String  ARG_PLANET_NUMBER   = "planet_number";

    public TryFragment()
    {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
           TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setText("Prueba");
            text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layout.addView(text);

            Log.d("TestFragment", "Estoy en el fragment");

            return layout;
    }
}
```

I do not know if I have to destroy the viewpager to show the new fragment or a problem of hierarchy in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewPager must be Fragment, and it should be placed to layout.content_frame, so when you calling ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment); your ViewPager fragment will be replaced.

Comment: I dont understand you.

Comment: As i understand you need to replace ViewPager, when selecting another item from nav drawer. So you need to put ViewPager to separate Fragment, and put it to contant_frame when needed.

Comment: I have 3 option, the first and second tabs are ViewPager and the third is that I have to remove the ViewPager shows that fragment.

Comment: Then you need to hide content_linear when selectiong option 3

Comment: findViewById(R.id.content_linear).SetVisibitity(View.GONE); ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

Comment: And ViewPager and NavigationDrawer is two different UI pattern. I think mix them is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will change the ViewPager with TabHost.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ViewPager and NavigationDrawer at the same time. You can see Roman Nurik's answer in this G+ post:
https://plus.google.com/u/1/+DavidTaSmoochibi/posts/8dWEkFcbTFX

"You shouldn't use navigation drawers with action bar tabs. If you're aiming for a UI similar to that of Google Play Music, you should implement tabs manually (and beware of how this looks on tablet—you don't want full-width tab bars on tablets). Also make sure to check out the Structure in Android App Design session from this year's Google I/O for a detailed run-through of the various interface patterns available for exposing app hierarchy."

Comment: The problem is that if I use actionbar tabs this show over tabs this is shown below the tabs. With the only thing that has not happened to me this is with ViewPager.